# I can't make this JavaScript count working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a button (out of divs) and a paragraph (or any text field) below the divs that counts the clicks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#butt').mousedown(function() {
    $("#butt").hide();

  });
  $("#pushed").mouseup(function() {
    $("#butt").show();

  });
  $("#butt").click(function() {
    button_click();
  });
});


var clicks = 0;

function button_click() {
  clicks = parseInt(clicks) + parseInt(1);
  var divData = document.getElementById("showCount");
  divData.innerHTML = "Clicks:" + clicks;
}
```

```html
<!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css"/> -->
<form name="ButtonForm">
  <div id="container">

    <div id="pushed"></div>

    <div id="butt"></div>

  </div>

  <div id="showCount"></div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--<script src="Untitled-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Basically, click isn't registered at all, because you hide button on mousedown. What that code should do at all? When you remove that code and apply simple counter, all works: https://jsfiddle.net/1tpj1box/

Comment: What's the point of `parseInt(1);`? I would expect that to throw. Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Your `div` elements are empty and there is no CSS to give them any explicit size, so they will never be visible for you to click on them.

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` on an ***int***?  `parseInt(1)` can be replaced with literally just `1`.  Also you can do `clicks = clicks + 1;` (or even `clicks += 1;` or `clicks++;`).

Comment: @Carcigenicate: `parseInt(1)` actually works.  The `1` is cast as a string and then parsed as an int.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Good point, but technically, all numbers in JavaScript are floats, there are no ints.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: True, but just for the sake of trying to explain this...

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh, I guess I could have guessed that. Wasn't sure if it contained a type assertion or not.

Comment: Why are you using `mousedown` and `mouseup` events here?  Why not just `click`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here is a simplified example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOrRBp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div` elements are empty and there is no CSS to give them any explicit size, so they will never be visible for you to click on them.

Also, the `mousedown` event handler can and should be combined with the `click` handler for `butt` and the `mouseup` event handler should just be a `click` event as well.

Additionally, you only need to update the number of clicks, not the word "Clicks", so make a separate placeholder for the number with a `span` element and then you can hard-code the word "Clicks" into the `div`.

Lastly, to increment a number by one, you can just use the pre or post-increment operator (++).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicks = 0;
  var divData = $("#clickCount");
  
  $("#pushed").on("click", function() {
    $("#butt").show();
  });
  
  $("#butt").on("click", function() {
    $("#butt").hide();
    clicks++;  // increment the counter by one
    divData.html(clicks);
  });
});
```

```css
#pushed, #butt {height:50px; width:150px; background-color:green; margin:5px;}
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="ButtonForm">
    <div id="container">

      <div id="pushed"></div>

      <div id="butt"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="showCount">Clicks <span id="clickCount"></span></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should simplify your code. Hiding and showing the button is not necessary to produce the result you are looking for.

Second, change the #butt element to an actual button so that you have something to see and click.

Third, make sure your script is loading after jquery is included.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<button id="butt">I'm a button</button>
<div id="showCount"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#butt").click(function() {
    button_click();
  });

  var clicks = 0;

  function button_click() {
    clicks = parseInt(clicks) + parseInt(1);
    var divData = document.getElementById("showCount");
    divData.innerHTML = "Clicks:" + clicks;
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to count how many times the second `div` is being hidden. Also, the use of `div` elements isn't a deal-breaker here. These issues should be addressed in the answer.